# Troubleshooting Modbus Connection Issue: “Failed to connect” Error

Tags: ros2

I am currently working on a project that involves communication between a ROS (Robot Operating System) environment and an Allen-Bradley CompactLogix PLC using Modbus TCP. I have encountered an issue with the Modbus connection, and I would appreciate any guidance or insights on resolving it.

Problem Description:

I am attempting to send data from ROS to the 1769-L16ER-BB1B Allen Bradley CompactLogix PLC. However, when running the provided Python code snippet, I am encountering the following error:

Modbus Error: [Connection] Failed to connect [ModbusTcpClient 192.168.1.1:502]

Code Snippet:

python

def move_robot_thread(self):
plc_ip = '192.168.1.1'
plc_port = 502

```
# Create a synchronous ModbusTcpClient instance
client = ModbusTcpClient(plc_ip, plc_port)

try:
    for point in self.palletizing_pattern:
        x, y, z = point
        x_register_value = int(x * 100)  # Convert to an appropriate integer value
        y_register_value = int(y * 100)
        z_register_value = int(z * 100)

        # Write the coordinates to Modbus registers
        client.write_registers(0, [x_register_value, y_register_value, z_register_value])

        print(f"Published pose: x={x}, y={y}, z={z}")
        print("Waiting for response...")

        # Introduce a delay (adjust the duration as needed)
        time.sleep(6)

    print("All poses published.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during Modbus communication: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the Modbus connection
    client.close()
```

def move_robot(self):
# Create a new thread for move_robot_thread function
move_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.move_robot_thread)
# Start the new thread
move_thread.start()

Include relevant import statements

!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

from std_msgs.msg import String

from std_srvs.srv import Trigger

from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

import rclpy

import sys

import threading

from rclpy.task import Future

import time

Additional Information:

ROS version: humble
Python version: 3.10.12
Allen Bradley PLC model: 1769-L16ER-BB1B
Network configuration: modbus tcp

Questions:

What could be causing the "Failed to connect" Modbus error?
Are there specific considerations for Modbus communication with the Allen Bradley CompactLogix PLC?
How can I troubleshoot and diagnose the Modbus connection issue?

Any help or advice on resolving this Modbus connection problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,